# Vistas y render() en Django

Tags: python, django, python-2.7

Estoy aprendiendo a utilizar Django (específicamente la versión 1.9). Sin embargo, al momento de crear una vista, y al iniciar el servidor de Django, tengo el siguiente error:

```
TypeError: render() takes at least 2 arguments (1 given)
```

Lo que no entiendo es, ¿qué otros parámetros debe tener el método `render()`, aparte de la dirección de la vista (considerando que es estática)?
Este error fue corregido con la adición de parámetros faltantes. Sin embargo, ahora se me presenta el siguiente error, el cual no sé por qué se presenta:

```
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'regex'
```

En mi archivo views.py de mi aplicación, tengo lo siguiente (CORREGIDO):

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.template import Template

def index(request):
    template_name = '/app/web/index.html'
    return render(request, template_name)
```

En cuanto a mi archivo de URLs, éste tiene lo siguiente:

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from django.contrib import admin
import app.views

urlpatterns = ['',
    # Vista para pagina de inicio
    url(r'^$', app.views.index),
    # Otras vistas
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    ]`
```

Y en el archivo de configuración, edité en parte la sección de templates, agregando la carpeta en donde está mi página en cuestión:

```
# Application definition
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'app'
    )

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    )

ROOT_URLCONF = 'vehiculos.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [
            '/app/web',
        ],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'vehiculos.wsgi.application'

# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': 'vehiculos',
        'USER': 'root',
        'PASSWORD': '',
        # 'HOST': 'localhost'
        # 'PORT': '3306',
    }
}

# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'es-CL'
TIME_ZONE = 'America/Argentina/Mendoza'
USE_I18N = True
USE_L10N = True
USE_TZ = True

# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

Muchas gracias de antemano

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La función [`render`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/http/shortcuts/#render) debe recibir como primer parámetro el `request` de la vista que va a ser renderizada:

```
def index(request):
    template_name = '/app/web/index.html'
    return render(request, template_name)
```

El `request` y el nombre de tu template (`template_name`) son los parámetros mínimos que debe recibir la funcion `render`. Sería bueno que expliques la razón por la cual definiste tu función de esa manera, tomando como parámetro de la vista el `template`. Esto está mal:

```
def index(template='/app/web/index.html'):
    return render(template)`
```

Las [vistas](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/http/views/#writing-views) son funciones que obtienen un `request` y retornan una respuesta o `response`.

Con respecto a la URL:

```
url(r'^$', app.views.index())
```

No debes llamar a la función, solo debes pasar la referencia (sin usar paréntesis):

```
url(r'^$', app.views.index)
```

También puedes usar una cadena con la ruta a la función y con esto evitas estar importando `app`:

```
url(r'^$', 'app.views.index')
```

### Actualización

Al parecer el problema es la definición de tus URLs ya que en la versión que estás usando `urlpatterns` es ahora una lista y el primer elemento `''` es inválido. Cámbialo a:

```
urlpatterns = [
    # Vista para pagina de inicio
    url(r'^$', app.views.index),
    # Otras vistas
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
]
```

Comment: La razón es que no entendí muy bien cómo se utilizaba el request más que nada  y estuve mirando algunos tutoriales de una versión más antigua de Django que no mostraban mucha explicación del tema. Ahora, al haber corregido el método, me sale el siguiente error:
`AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'regex'` , sospecho ahora que es por la URL. Gracias por la explicación.

Comment: @Ryuuko ¿qué error? Deberías consultar siempre la documentación oficial que está actualizada. Los tutoriales normalmente se desactualizan.

Comment: @Ryuuko mira mi actualización

Comment: Corregí el tema del paréntesis, pero sigo teniendo el error indicado anteriormente. También probé con la otra forma de expresar la url con el string de la ruta, pero me sale la advertencia quee ya no será utilizado.

Comment: @Ryuuko ¿que versión de Django estás usando? Edita tu pregunta e incluye el código completo de tus archivos

Comment: Agregué el contenido completo de los archivos

Comment: @Ryuuko ya actualicé mi respuesta

Comment: En este caso no sería mejor usar vistas basadas en clase?